# react-bootstrap giving 'Unknown props' for 'position' on Tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to implement vertically stacked tabs in my React app, and I was excited to see this pull request merged into `react-bootstrap` https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/1143

The problem is that I've been receiving `` Warning: Unknown props `position`, `tabWidth` on <ul> tag. Remove these props from the element ``

Here is my code;

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey={2} position='left' tabWidth={3} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
  <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">Tab 1 content</Tab>
  <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">Tab 2 content</Tab>
  <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" disabled>Tab 3 content</Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: you'll see that error if a particular prop is not implemented. Check your react-bootstrap version once again

Comment: If you are on the latest version, you may want to open an issue on the repo, or better yet, fix it and open a PR.